# Workflow failed to get user profile for user:1234

Tags: designer-workflow, user-profile, error

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 designer list workflow. The logic is quite simple. When a new item is added to the list (it is a calendar), the workflow will be triggered. One of step is to get the requester's user profile "Manager" field. However, it always return `Workflow failed to get user profile for user:1234` and the workflow result in `Error Occurred`.

However, if I terminate the error workflow, start the same workflow manually, everything will work. "Manager" field can be returned without error.

I checked user profile 1234 is valid as well as all the test users on this farm.

Would it be permission issue? However I have no clue where to check.

Comment: looks like permission issue. use impersonation step

Comment: you can check in AD whether user1234 has the manager. because if manager is not configured for the user, in this case it will give this error. or if manager is configured then check while getting the manager it should be string(internally it accept account name to find the manager)

Comment: yes, manager value is existing, otherwise it will not work when I manually run it.

Comment: @MarkL, sorry i have edited my comment, please see.

Comment: Mark, were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: it is 2 years ago and I have left the environment... I remember Abhishek's suggestion about data type "string" help me.